# How do I create a Unity 3D UI text element in an F# script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#

I'm attempting to create some ui elements in my F# script that is attached to a camera in Unity 3d. I know how to do this in `C#` but I'm not quite sure how to do it in `F#`.

Here's a simple `C#` example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text uiText;

    void Start ()
    {
        uiText.text = "Hello world!";
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }
}
```

Now, here's my `F#` code. I've added comments that displays the compiler error I get when attempting to create a text element, `This type has no accessible constructors`.

```
namespace GameLogic

open UnityEngine
open UnityEngine.UI

type CameraController() =
    inherit MonoBehaviour()

    member this.uiText = Text // Compiler Error: This type has no accessible constructors
    member this.Start() =
        let uiText = Text // Compiler Error: This Type has no accessible constructors
        ()

    member this.Update() =
        ()
```

It seems like `F#` implicitly calls a constructor method on Unity's `Text` object.

So, how can I create a ui text element in an F# script? Thanks for any and all help.

Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C# code, the `uiText` member is getting initialized with `null`, which is the default for C#. In F#, there is no "default", you have to write the initial value explicitly:

```
member this.uiText: Text = null
```

This will compile, but won't give you the desired result. This syntax will create a read-only property that always returns `null`. In order to create a read/write property with initial value, you have to use `member val`:

```
member val uiText: Text = null with get, set
```

The 'get, set' part in there serves for clarification that you want the property to be readable *and* writable. Without it (by default), the property will be read-only.

For a complete description of how properties work in F#, [see MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a mutable `let` binding that specifies it is of type `Text` and its initial value is `null`. I then added the `SerializeField` attribute in order to associate `UI Text` elements in the Unity editor with the script.

Below is a simple example.

```
namespace GameLogic

open UnityEngine
open UnityEngine.UI

type CameraController() =
    inherit MonoBehaviour()

    [<SerializeField>]
    let mutable uiText : Text = null

    member this.Start() =
        uiText.text <- "hello world!"
        ()

    member this.Update() =
        ()
```